# Why is .htaccess ignoring "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [NC]"?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

Since I declare it should only redirect if it is NOT an "https://" request, this code should not redirect from index.rd1.html to index.rd2.html if I type "https://example.com/index.rd1.html" in the url, but it does. Why?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.rd1.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.rd2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That seems correct. Did you empty your cache? Redirects are cached too and can be tricky to debug when modifying them.

Comment: I cleared all history, quit Safari, reopened it, and it still redirected when I typed in the https url.

Comment: Is this apache running behind some kind of load balancer or reverse proxy?

Comment: I received a reply from hostway.com (which hosts the site) and I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that hostway.com (which is hosting the site) does not have the standard .htaccess rules. In order for it to detect https I had to add "ENV:" before HTTPS as done here:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
```

Comment: Lame. how did you find that out?